# Application Pool Crash During Loop (Not an Infinite Loop)

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

As stated in the title,
I have a web application where user supposed to upload an excel file, 
the system will then read it and put it inside a recordset, then it will loop it to read one by one data to be processed into database.

Problem is, it can process small data just fine, but when I try to process around 919 record, it stuck at around 890 record and the application pool just stopped by itself, I'm guessing it crashed.

I've tried putting response.flush for every 100 record to no avail. Running the process inside the server itself gives me this error around 890 record, 
An unhandled win32 exception occurred in w3wp.exe.

Thanks in advance.

The code is in classic asp, vbscript

My Initial Code :

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")   
dim tmpRS
objConn.open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & folderPath & "\" & fname_ & "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'"

Set cat = Server.CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
cat.ActiveConnection = objConn

For tnum = 0 To cat.Tables.count - 1
    Set tbl = cat.Tables(tnum)

    set objRS = server.createObject("ADODB.recordset")
    objRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & tbl.Name & "]" , objConn
    if objRs.eof = false Then
        set tmpRS = mydb("INSERT INTO tmpTable VALUES ('" & TRIM(objrs.fields.item(0)) & "')", 3)
        set tmpRS = nothing
    end if
    set objrs = nothing

Next
objConn.close
```

Current Solution That I Found :

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")   
dim tmpRS
objConn.open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & folderPath & "\" & fname_ & "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'"

set objRS = server.createObject("ADODB.recordset")
objRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]" , objConn
if objRs.eof = false Then
    set tmpRS = mydb("INSERT INTO tmpTable VALUES ('" & TRIM(objrs.fields.item(0)) & "')", 3)
    set tmpRS = nothing
end if
set objrs = nothing
```

I would be very grateful if someone can point out what is the problem with my initial code.

Comment: can you post some code? so we can see how you're processing that file. 
also - check the file around that point where it crashes...can you extract a batch of the records around it and try and process them as a smaller file (to rule out the data being an issue)

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, I've finally found a solution to my problem, though I couldn't find the reasoning for the problem to happen, if you happen to see the problem please point it out for me, thanks alot. The first code is my problem code, the second one is the current code that I used which works.